# Unable to lift parent window exist under child window in Tkinter? (Python 3.6.6, Windows 7 Ultimate)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Below is my test module:

```
import tkinter as tk
def startUi():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Parent Window")
    window.geometry("500x200")
    rgButton = tk.Button(window,text="  Open Child",command=openChildWindow)   
    rgButton.pack()
    window.mainloop()

def openChildWindow():
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.title("Child Window")
    window.geometry("200x200")

startUi()
```

After running the above code why am I not able to lift the parent window to front just after clicking the button. i.e after clicking the button the child window will show in front of parent window, however when I click on the space area of the parent window I am not able to bring the parent window up to the front.

I am able to bring it up to front only by:

- Clicking on the border of the parent window
- Clicking on child window once and then clicking on the Parent again.

This not a normal behavior. Why is it so? And How will I solve it? I want to achieve the normal behavior i.e. I want to bring the parent window up in front of the child on clicking **anywhere** on the parent window.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (python 3.7, linux), when I click anywhere on the parent, it brings it in front of the child.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on osx. Are you running on a windows machine?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I am running on Windows